# web analytics works but skipping a site collection

Tags: web-analytics

Are there any reason why web analytics quit runing analytics on one of the site? Just start happening for past few weeks. But it run well on all other site collections (about 40 site collections) and all mysite (about 350 mysites which is site collection) except one of the mysite. so past 2 weeks it quit reporting for one of the site that is in mysite.